# How to range vertex select in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, select, vertices

I am a QGIS 2 user and trying to use vertex tool in QGIS 3.
I noticed that there is a feature for QGIS3:
https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-range-vertex-selection-in-node-tool.
The diagram interested me, how convenient it is! This means that I can move a inner filled ring of a polygon.
for example, (from A to B)
[image]

Anyway, I use vertex tool awkwardly, I tried the Shift+R key but I can't make any solid blue selection,

[image]

[image]

My selections shown in the picture, are blue hollow circles.
How to make a blue solid selection?